# How do I concatenate my element id in this scenario?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

How can I get the selected text for a drop down in the below scenario?

```
    var abc = $("#ddlReason"+bidId+"option:selected").html();
```

As you see above, "bidId" is a variable that I need to suffix with the dropdown id "ddlReason".

Comment: Use ths `$("#ddlReason"+bidId+" option:selected").text()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string.Format("#{0}{1} option:selected", ddlReason, bidId);
```

this will build your string the way you want it.